# Giving alias name with space in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column in my query for which I want to use its **alias** name.

Currently it is looking like this:

```
SELECT U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name UserName,
```

But I want to use it as like below

```
SELECT U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name as User Name,
```

I tried but I got error as:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Comment: `as "User Name"`. (ANSI SQL way, works well with MS SQL Server, I think...)

Comment: @jarlh: perfectly worked.. Was unaware of this kind of small thing.. thanks a lot for this :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Double quotes for alias with a space.

```
SELECT U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name AS "User Name"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt.!

Comment: What about single quotes?

Answer (score 14):

Try This

```
SELECT U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name as [User Name]
```